# 'he request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nodes, amazon-sqs

show this error. i can't fix this error anyone please help this issue.

'he request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.

app.js

```
    const AWS =require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({region :  'us-west-2'});
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./config.json');
const sqs = new AWS.SQS({apiVersion:  '2012-11-05'});
const queueURL = "https://sqs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXX.fifo";

const params = {
    AttributeNames:[
        "SentTimestamp"
    ],
    MaxNumberOfMessages:1,
    MessageAttributeNames:[
        "All"
    ],
    QueueUrl:queueURL,
    VisibilityTimeout:0,
    WaitTimeSeconds:0
};

    sqs.receiveMessage(params,function (err,data) {
        console.log(data);
        console.log(err);
    });
```

config.json

```
{
    "aws_access_key_id":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "aws_secret_access_key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "region":"us-west-2"
}
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that your access key and secret access key are in fact correct?

Comment: thank you. my access key is wrong.